# Using of hash(map) as key in durable cache

Tags: clojure

I'm going to use redis cache where key is a clojure map (serialized into bytes by nippy).

Can i use hash of the clojure map as a key in redis cache?

Another words, does clojure map hash depends *only* on data structure value and does not depend on any memory allocation.

Investigating:

I navigated through code and found out `IHashEq` interface which is implemented by clojure data structures.
In the result, `IHashEq` impl ends with calling of `Object.hashCode` which has following contract:

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during
>   an execution of a Java application, the `{@code hashCode}` method
>   must consistently return the same integer, provided no information
>   used in `{@code equals}` comparisons on the object is modified.
>   This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an
>   application to another execution of the same application.

Well, just want to clarify that i *cannot* use hash as id persistent in other process because:

- two equal values give two equal hash codes, but not vice verse. So there is a chance of collision
- there is no guarantee that clojure map hash will be the same for the the same values in different jvm processes

Please, confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Re your two points:

- Two equal values will yield the same hash code, but two unequal values may also give the same hash code.  So the chance of collision makes this a bad choice of key.
- Different JVM's should generate the same hashcode for a given value, given the same version of Java & Clojure (& very probably for different versions, although this is not guarenteed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use secure hash library (like this [one](https://github.com/arachne-framework/valuehash)) to address your concerns (like in blockchain). Albeit you have to pay for its performance penalty.